# PyCharm not recognizing package in root directory

Tags: package, pycharm

I have a PyCharm project in a directory `pearl`, which is marked as a sources root directory (blue).

[image]

However, the directory is not recognized as a package:

[image]

I'm using Python 3.8, so a file `__init__.py` is not necessary to mark a directory as a package.

What's wrong?